# Issues with "Deadlocks" in WCF routing service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I've tried a few different ways to do this, but I keep coming up short.

In short, here's what I need to do:

Create a WCF service that acts as a router between client (desktop pc) run diagnostic tools and "widgets" (that also run desktop windows and are have internet connectivety). Since these "widgets" are typically behind some sort of firewall, we've decided to use an IIS hosted WCF service over a tcp connection (port 800, i believe) for callbacks.

Notifications of what the widget is doing need to be sent, asyncronously up through the router to any "connection" clients.

Clients need to be able to syncronously call into the widgets to get diagnostic data or command them to perform a task.

Right now I have a windows service running on the widget that monitors it's status and provided a link to the internal programs to get data.

I also have a light weight diagnostic application running on desktops.

I have created a single callback interface for both status-push and data-pulls that both the widget monitoring program and desktop program implement.

My first attempt was to have the router service keep a list of registered devices and clients and pass messages between them.

Ie: Desktop calls `server.getwidgetcolor("widgetid");` and the service calls `_widgetlist["widgetId"].getcolor()` and returns it.

Similarly the widget monitoring program calls `server.notifywidgetcolorchange("widgetid")` and the service calls, on all registered client `_widgetlist["widgetid"].clients.Notifiycolorchange()`

The problem I am running into is that if a wigdet is calling up to the server at the same time the client is calling down to that widget, both calls timeout.

I initially had the server setup as a singleton, and have played with changing the concurancy mode to multiple or re-entrant, but those didn't seem to work.

Conceptually, i'd like to have the service be per-call and persist somehow, that device and client call backs so that when a call comes in, the server wakes up, depersists the call back, sends the message, then goes back to sleep.

With all that said:

1. Is that ^^ possible (to persist call-back data so that a per-call server can call back on clients)? If not, could I make the service per session (for clients/widgets) but pass the data between service sessions through some other means? Shared memory? File?
2. Is the over all design possible/recommended? I've looked into the WCF routing library, but that doesn't seem to do what I want, unless I'm reading it wrong?
3. Are there other technologies I should be using that can do this more easily?

Thanks,

-Bill